# Iterate through keys/values in Hogan.js

Tags: javascript, templating, hogan.js

Is there a way to iterate through keys and values in an object using Hogan.js? I'm unable to find such documented functionality - only iteration over arrays seems to be documented. Is it even possible to iterate through objects in hogan.js (or any other moustache.js implementation)?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to directly iterate over the keys and values in an object in Hogan.js, what sub_stantial is doing is essentialy iterating over an array.

Depending on what you want to do you need a bit of prerender code. Supposing you have an object o that is `{ k1: "v1", k2: "v2" }`. And you want your rendered template to be `k1 has value v1; k2 has value v2;`, you only need this (_ is the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library):

```
var oAsList = [];
_.each(_.keys(oAsList), function (k) {
  oAsList.push({ key: k, value: o[k] });
})
```

And the Mustache template that does the trick is
`{{#oAsList}} {{key}} has value {{value}}; {{/oAsList}}`

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation yesterday, and after some research with `Hogan.js` and `Mustache.js`, I found this solution :

```
var data = { 'list' : [{ 'name' : 'dhg'}, {'name' : 'abc'}] };
var template = Hogan.compile("{{#list}} {{name}} {{/list}}");
var output = template.render(data);
console.log(output);
```

You can see it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/LuD6j/1/